Error ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "application.js" is not present in the asset pipeline
I have a Rails app where I have setup a Javascript entrypoint with a React component also adding Tailwind using jsbundling-rails, esbuild and cssbundling-rails.
In development mode, the first time I start the server wit the assets/builds folder empty, I got the error in the title, if I stop and start again, everything works fine, both js and css, but when I deploy it to production even though the build completes succesfully, in first reload the app crashes with the error in the title ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "application.js" is not present in the asset pipeline. The problem persists even if I restart the production server unlike in development.
I guess it has to be something related to manifest.js but I don't see where the problem is.
These are the relevant files:
manifest.js
//= link_tree ../images
//= link application.css
//= link_tree ../../javascript .js
//= link_tree ../../../vendor/javascript .js
//= link_tree ../builds

scripts in package.json
 "scripts": {
    "build": "esbuild app/javascript/entrypoints/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets",
    "build:css": "tailwindcss -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.css -o ./app/assets/builds/application.css"
  },

application.html.erb
  <head>
    <title>ReactOnRailsPoc</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
    <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload", type: "module" %>
  </head>

folder structure:
app/
├── assets/
│   └── build/
│       ├── application.js
│       ├── application.css
│       └── application.js.map

app/
├── assets/
│   └── build/
│       ├── application.js
│       ├── application.css
│       └── application.js.map
└── javascript/
    └── entrypoints/
        └── application.tsx

render-build.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# exit on error
set -o errexit

bundle install
bundle exec rails assets:precompile
# latest finding, running bundle exec rails assets:precompile twice in this script fixes the problem in production.
bundle exec rails assets:clean

# If you're using a Free instance type, you need to
# perform database migrations in the build command.
# Uncomment the following line:

bundle exec rails db:migrate

Dump of the logs from build stage in prod:
yarn install v1.22.22
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
Done in 4.17s.
yarn run v1.22.22
$ esbuild app/javascript/entrypoints/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets
  app/assets/builds/application.js      1.0mb ⚠️
  app/assets/builds/application.js.map  1.6mb
Done in 0.14s.
yarn install v1.22.22
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.10s.
yarn run v1.22.22
$ tailwindcss -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.css -o ./app/assets/builds/application.css
Rebuilding...
Done in 157ms.
Done in 0.51s.
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.135902 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/manifest-2f0ac84ec540eb753a59078be1e78cb9bb00e12a9a8d6d826039a818a0008610.js
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.136380 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/manifest-2f0ac84ec540eb753a59078be1e78cb9bb00e12a9a8d6d826039a818a0008610.js.gz
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.136587 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/application-3e0f79566f3719b31553f01790266e24caa6a3ba8bc9f222a5887ccffc0108c7.css
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.136750 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/application-3e0f79566f3719b31553f01790266e24caa6a3ba8bc9f222a5887ccffc0108c7.css.gz
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.136942 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/turbo-6f8f1796078d2d3f7cb9b6badcd2d5e76287a3c58d97baffaa59dd12bd4135f5.js
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.137120 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/turbo-6f8f1796078d2d3f7cb9b6badcd2d5e76287a3c58d97baffaa59dd12bd4135f5.js.gz
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.137422 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/turbo.min-918a6cf2f2be8ed9555c9a11eee69c7dc2f01770802815576efc931876b327fb.js
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.137693 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/turbo.min-918a6cf2f2be8ed9555c9a11eee69c7dc2f01770802815576efc931876b327fb.js.gz
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.138051 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/turbo.min.js-16b5fa18e8e95a86fc9f56ced2c8a9c83a99b73834da35ba1b2ff5dab550d7fa.map
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.138339 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/turbo.min.js-16b5fa18e8e95a86fc9f56ced2c8a9c83a99b73834da35ba1b2ff5dab550d7fa.map.gz
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.138661 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/actiontext-78de0ebeae470799f9ec25fd0e20ae2d931df88c2ff9315918d1054a2fca2596.js
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.138915 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/actiontext-78de0ebeae470799f9ec25fd0e20ae2d931df88c2ff9315918d1054a2fca2596.js.gz
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.139397 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/actiontext.esm-328ef022563f73c1b9b45ace742bd21330da0f6bd6c1c96d352d52fc8b8857e5.js
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.139682 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/actiontext.esm-328ef022563f73c1b9b45ace742bd21330da0f6bd6c1c96d352d52fc8b8857e5.js.gz
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.139959 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/trix-e17a480fcb4e30c8571f0fed42dc81de5faeef93755ca30fe9623eb3f5c709e5.js
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.140263 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/trix-e17a480fcb4e30c8571f0fed42dc81de5faeef93755ca30fe9623eb3f5c709e5.js.gz
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.140846 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/trix-91ad87f30d9c53c7b05f534dc3c9994e4e90d50dff03a7222c1326f342f9c223.css
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.141129 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/trix-91ad87f30d9c53c7b05f534dc3c9994e4e90d50dff03a7222c1326f342f9c223.css.gz
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.141385 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/stimulus-f75215805563870a61ee9dc5a207ce46d4675c7e667558a54344fd1e7baa697f.js
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.141678 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/stimulus-f75215805563870a61ee9dc5a207ce46d4675c7e667558a54344fd1e7baa697f.js.gz
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.141988 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/stimulus-autoloader-c584942b568ba74879da31c7c3d51366737bacaf6fbae659383c0a5653685693.js
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.142259 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/stimulus-autoloader-c584942b568ba74879da31c7c3d51366737bacaf6fbae659383c0a5653685693.js.gz
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.143035 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/stimulus-importmap-autoloader-db2076c783bf2dbee1226e2add52fef290b5d31b5bcd1edd999ac8a6dd31c44a.js
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.143375 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/stimulus-importmap-autoloader-db2076c783bf2dbee1226e2add52fef290b5d31b5bcd1edd999ac8a6dd31c44a.js.gz
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.143755 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/stimulus-loading-3576ce92b149ad5d6959438c6f291e2426c86df3b874c525b30faad51b0d96b3.js
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.144203 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/stimulus-loading-3576ce92b149ad5d6959438c6f291e2426c86df3b874c525b30faad51b0d96b3.js.gz
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.144626 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/stimulus.min-dd364f16ec9504dfb72672295637a1c8838773b01c0b441bd41008124c407894.js
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.145015 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/stimulus.min-dd364f16ec9504dfb72672295637a1c8838773b01c0b441bd41008124c407894.js.gz
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.145536 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/stimulus-autoloader-c584942b568ba74879da31c7c3d51366737bacaf6fbae659383c0a5653685693.js.gz
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.146085 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/stimulus-importmap-autoloader-db2076c783bf2dbee1226e2add52fef290b5d31b5bcd1edd999ac8a6dd31c44a.js.gz
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.146648 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/stimulus-loading-3576ce92b149ad5d6959438c6f291e2426c86df3b874c525b30faad51b0d96b3.js.gz
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.147011 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/stimulus.min.js-2cc63625fa177963b45da974806e7aee846cbf1d4930815733d0fdf3fb232325.map
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.147358 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/stimulus.min.js-2cc63625fa177963b45da974806e7aee846cbf1d4930815733d0fdf3fb232325.map.gz
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.147736 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/activestorage-503a4fe23aabfbcb752dad255f01835904e6961d5f20d1de13987a691c27d9cd.js
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.148003 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/activestorage-503a4fe23aabfbcb752dad255f01835904e6961d5f20d1de13987a691c27d9cd.js.gz
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.148373 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/activestorage.esm-b3f7f0a5ef90530b509c5e681c4b3ef5d5046851e5b70d57fdb45e32b039c883.js
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.148653 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/activestorage.esm-b3f7f0a5ef90530b509c5e681c4b3ef5d5046851e5b70d57fdb45e32b039c883.js.gz
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.148989 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/actioncable-1c7f008c6deb7b55c6878be38700ff6bf56b75444a086fa1f46e3b781365a3ea.js
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.149299 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/actioncable-1c7f008c6deb7b55c6878be38700ff6bf56b75444a086fa1f46e3b781365a3ea.js.gz
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.149744 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/actioncable.esm-06609b0ecaffe2ab952021b9c8df8b6c68f65fc23bee728fc678a2605e1ce132.js
I, [2024-08-20T21:25:26.150014 #1155]  INFO -- : Writing /opt/render/project/src/public/assets/actioncable.esm-06609b0ecaffe2ab952021b9c8df8b6c68f65fc23bee728fc678a2605e1ce132.js.gz
==> Uploading build...
==> Build uploaded in 8s
==> Build successful 
==> Deploying...
==> Using Node version 20.15.1 (default)
==> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
==> Using Bun version 1.1.0 (default)
==> Docs on specifying a bun version: https://render.com/docs/bun-version
==> Running 'bundle exec rails server'
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 7.1.3.2 application starting in production 
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
[112] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[112] * Puma version: 6.4.2 (ruby 3.3.0-p0) ("The Eagle of Durango")
[112] *  Min threads: 5
[112] *  Max threads: 5
[112] *  Environment: production
[112] *   Master PID: 112
[112] *      Workers: 2
[112] *     Restarts: (✔) hot (✖) phased
[112] * Preloading application
[112] * Listening on http://0.0.0.0:10000
[112] Use Ctrl-C to stop
[112] - Worker 0 (PID: 118) booted in 0.0s, phase: 0
[112] - Worker 1 (PID: 132) booted in 0.0s, phase: 0
==> Your service is live 
I, [2024-08-20T21:26:50.635015 #118]  INFO -- : [ee7ec919-1010-4c99-97ca-fb760bbdaf56] Started GET "/" for 34.83.207.104 at 2024-08-20 21:26:50 +0000
I, [2024-08-20T21:26:50.669291 #118]  INFO -- : [ee7ec919-1010-4c99-97ca-fb760bbdaf56] Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
W, [2024-08-20T21:26:50.678583 #118]  WARN -- : [ee7ec919-1010-4c99-97ca-fb760bbdaf56] Importmap skipped missing path: application.js
W, [2024-08-20T21:26:50.679026 #118]  WARN -- : [ee7ec919-1010-4c99-97ca-fb760bbdaf56] Importmap skipped missing path: application.js
I, [2024-08-20T21:26:50.679866 #118]  INFO -- : [ee7ec919-1010-4c99-97ca-fb760bbdaf56]   Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 5.1ms | Allocations: 1558)
I, [2024-08-20T21:26:50.680185 #118]  INFO -- : [ee7ec919-1010-4c99-97ca-fb760bbdaf56] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 2790)
E, [2024-08-20T21:26:50.682015 #118] ERROR -- : [ee7ec919-1010-4c99-97ca-fb760bbdaf56]   
[ee7ec919-1010-4c99-97ca-fb760bbdaf56] ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "application.js" is not present in the asset pipeline.
):
[ee7ec919-1010-4c99-97ca-fb760bbdaf56]      8: 
[ee7ec919-1010-4c99-97ca-fb760bbdaf56]      9:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
[ee7ec919-1010-4c99-97ca-fb760bbdaf56]     10:     <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
[ee7ec919-1010-4c99-97ca-fb760bbdaf56]     11:     <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload", type: "module" %>
[ee7ec919-1010-4c99-97ca-fb760bbdaf56]     12:   </head>
[ee7ec919-1010-4c99-97ca-fb760bbdaf56]     13: 
[ee7ec919-1010-4c99-97ca-fb760bbdaf56]     14:   <body class="bg-gray-100 min-h-screen flex flex-col">
[ee7ec919-1010-4c99-97ca-fb760bbdaf56]   
[ee7ec919-1010-4c99-97ca-fb760bbdaf56] app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11


Very bizarre, if I run twice, one run after another, of the command rails assets:precompile as part of my render-build.sh script, then the app starts fine

I've been working through some of the js bundler issues as well, to the point I've learned enough to have a good shot at an answer here. The main error '"application.js" is not present in the asset pipeline.' probably refers to the paths in your assets.rb initializer. Check that those Javascript directory paths are reflected there, ie. Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'javascript', 'entrypoints'). Particularly try to add in any paths you're seeing errors about, and compare with your manifest.js.
Couple other potential issues I see from your question:

In folder structure you call the folder 'build' rather than 'builds'.
It looks like you're trying 2-3 different approaches to serving/bundling your assets here. You're not trying to use importmaps but it's still in your code (importmap_tags), active and looking for your application.js file. And it's possible that after bundling the javascript with esbuild, rails is taking the bundled javascript from /builds and unnecessarily processing them again with precompile. Would advise looking into the documentation (not quite sure which) to sort it out, and along the way likely your precompiling twice issue.
You probably also have an esbuild config file at your app root with relevant settings to look at.

